# Adding posts from a custom post type as WooCommerce variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm building a Wordpress/WooCommerce website and I want to attach a custom post type to the WooCommerce variations. eg. Custom post type is 'paper thickness' and I want to be able to select a paper thickness from a drop down list within the Product's WooCommerce variations.

This will be in the product edit page so on the front end it will show details related to the variation based on the custom post that was selected.

Is there a way to do this with or without a plugin?

Comment: I'm curious as to why... because, in the end, depending on how you'll code it, it won't be useful. I'm saying, your question is not clear. There are so many ways I can think of doing this, but which is which will depend on why you would want it.

Comment: @Reigel, apologies, let me try and clarify; I want the client to have a set number of choices for variations so I thought I could set it as a custom post type. If there is a way to just define set options for a variation then that would suffice too.